# How to update a button's background color with a computed value on hover event?

Tags: jquery, html

This is probably a very stupid question but I can't figure out a way to insert the background-color of each button when hovering over each one. Currently its only displaying the background-color of the first button.

HTML:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Click Me</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Hello World!</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Click Other Button</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Last Button</button>
```

jQuery:

```
var prop = $("button").css("background-color");

$("button").hover(function(){
    $("button").each(function(){
        $(this).html(prop);
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/377/

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this

```
$("button").hover(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).css("background-color"));
});
```

[**Example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/380/)

Comment: Thank you, this is precisely what I wanted. People need not read a question so quickly and give a hastily response.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way,

```
$("button").hover(function(){
    $("button").css("background-color", "red");    
});
```

**Edit**, If you want to show the color as html of button, you can do it like

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/379/)**

```
$("button").hover(function(){
     $(this).html($(this).css("background-color")); 
});
```

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for, please re-read the question.

Comment: @Livingston - It seems as though this is the answer to the question you asked. Are you looking for something different than what you asked? Maybe the question needs clarification.

Comment: I want to insert the computed background color of *each* button into the content of the button itself. So if I hover over one, I get it's computed `rgb()` value. Right now only the first is being shown.

Comment: @LivingstonStorm - did you try the solution or are you just assuming it doesn't work?

Comment: @j08691: I tried it. Refer to my previous comment for what I want.

Comment: There could be any number of reasons why you have the variable prop. You didn't specify in the question why you have it. I'm just saying that if what you want to accomplish is not answered by this answer, you may need to clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to the `RGB` values of specific colors that used by each button. In that case you need to find it for every button but currently you are fetching it only for the first option so try this

```
$("button").hover(function(){
    $("button").each(function(){
        $(this).html($(this).css("background-color"););
    });
});
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/381/)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your fiddle, I'm guessing you want to see the color of each button. But you only set `prop` once, so only see the color of the first button. Try `this` instead.

```
$("button").hover(function(){
    $("button").each(function(){
        $(this).html($(this).css("background-color"));
    });
});
```